# Typescript does not want to spread type that's object by exclusion

Tags: typescript, javascript-objects, spread

I'm having issues spreading an externally imported type that's an `object` by way of `Exclude`. To demonstrate:

```js
const f = (): object => ({});
const v = {...f()}; // valid -> OK
```

```js
const f = (): object | string => ({});
const v = {...f()}; // invalid -> OK
```

```js
const f = (): Exclude<object | string, "string"> => ({});
const v = {...f()}; // invalid -> PROBLEM
```

In the last snippet I would expect the `Exclude` to make the type valid. Is this me thinking about it wrongly, or is there another way of fixing this? (the type exemplified by `object` is an external import I can't change).

Comment: Can you fix your examples ?  They're not valid TS.

Comment: Apologies, fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo in the `exclude` : You want to exclude the type `string` not the type `"string"` (which is a `string` that can only have the value `"string"`)

```
const f = (): Exclude<object | string, string> => ({});
const v = { ...f2() }; // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZjAvDAFASgFwxAIwFYCmwsAPjNAE4CWYA5kgHyoDeAvmgNwBQoksAbkhjMYAOnFx0MVhxgB6OTBr8AhgBsqAExgBaJgHkA0lx7ho8AExD0WAKIAPYGoCumggB5chYjDKUatAA05FDUdEyITChsnKZ8MPxWyCLionAWUjLyiiAA1lxAA)

Comment: Sorry, as you pointed out the syntax was wrong. The problem type is the return from the function (see updated OP)

Comment: Ah of course, thanks!